# image map edge detection

Tags: html, imagemap, edge-detection

if i have a map - say, of the united states, or an anatomy picture of the human body, or some sort of image with discrete sections, and i have a plain black and white outline of the image, what is the easiest way to determine the co-ordinates of the discrete sections, for use in an html image map?

I've used the coffee cup map maker, which is tedious (but also the best manual image-map maker i could find). Is there something - maybe free, maybe expensive - that can do this task automatically?

cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate HTML-Map from image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314181/generate-html-map-from-image)

Comment: hm, probably. but it would be nice to see if the worlds has advanced in 3 years!

Answer (score 2):

I quite like [iMapBuilder](http://www.imapbuilder.com/), I installed the [Chrome app](http://gstub.be/xFoOLz) and find it very easy to create image maps there for both regular and irregular areas.

You can import your image, set the area and actions, then simply add the embed code to your site.

I don't create too many image maps so maybe this isn't quite what you're looking for but I hope it helps.